# Do Java Iterators or Enhanced Loops guarantee results in order of creation?

Tags: java, sorting

Do `Java` `Iterators` or `Enhanced Loops` guarantee results in order of insertion? Please if the answer requires it, expand out an elaborate how Java handles ordering.

Examples of actual data structures in question:

```
1. Vector<String[]>
2. Iterator<String[]>
```

But my question was curious about all various data structures.

**The problem in question concerns Oracle SQL database results. I run an ordered query and I wish to access the data in this exact order.**

Comment: ...In what context? What do you mean by "order of creation"? What data structures are you using?

Comment: It depends on the underlying datastructure.

Comment: From the java.util.Set iterator() API: `The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).` From java.util.List: `Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.`

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, I edited the question to include data structures I am currently using, but I am curious about all forms of data structures. This is all about SQL database results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java doesn't provide any guarantees for these however, in certain cases, items will be iterated in a particular order:

- Lists and arrays will iterate over elements in order
- TreeSet in sort order
- LinkedHashSet in creation order

It all depends on what you're iterating over, and the particular implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "order of insertion" and not "creation". If that is so, the answer is yes for ordered collections like ArrayList for example.

Comment: not in order of creation though; though it depends; question is unclear

Comment: Ya, question is unclear, but I think I know what he means by it.

Comment: He probably meant order of insertion.

Comment: @Adrian, I did mean order of insertion, not instantiation (creation). Apologies for the confusion. I have modified the question.

Comment: @CodeBlue, what about Vector?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

It depends on the type of the collection. For example - ArrayList will be iterated in the order of addition, but set will not.

Comment: Verctor implements list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: I know. I just wanted clarification I wasn't missing anything, and that Vector will return in the order of addition too, as `ArrayList` does built upon `List`.

Answer (score 2):

The enhanced loop is just interpreted like using an iterator by Java runtime.
The total answer is no. For example when using SortedSets, or HashSets and ... the order of retrieving items is not the same as order of adding items to the Collection.

Lists are collections which shall reserve the order of items putting in them.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know enhanced loops are the same as iterators.